# Classic asp and ajax

Tags: ajax, post, asp-classic

I have problem with getting value from ajax to asp. I have form with select input field and if I select one option (from select options). I want to change my form action tag value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#preLin").change(function(){
        if ($('#preLin option:selected').val() === "Test" ) {
              var actionTag = "printHosp.his";
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "http://local:8001/Default.his",
                 data: {actionTag: "test.asp"},
                 success: function(data) { 
                 alert(actionTag);}
             });    
});
```

ASP

```
dim actionTag
actionTag = Request.form("actionTag")

<form action="<%=actionTag%>" name="input" method="post" target="_blank">

            <select name="preLin" id="preLin">
                <optgroup >
                        <option value="Test"></option>
                        <option value=""></option>                                          
                 </optgroup>

    </form>
```

Comment: what's the problem so far? Why do you post data to something, instead of element editing.

Comment: Besides, you forgot </select> in your asp page.

Answer (score 0):

There's best practices to do what you want, but i suggest you to solve this problem by adding a "**ajax error function**", then analyzing the `responseText`.

Change your ajax call for something like:

```
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://eli.local:8001/priemimas/Default.his",
          data: {actionTag: "test.asp"},
          success: function(data) {alert(actionTag);},
          error: function(xhr) {alert(xhr.responseText);}
      });
```